# Calculating mod polynomials, e.g. $\,a^2 = a+3\,\Rightarrow\, a^3 = \, \ldots\, $

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials

[image]

**This is a Belgian math olympiad question.**
https://www.vwo.be/vwo/files/2r2017.pdf

Sorry, the picture is in Dutch I will translate it:

If $a^2 -a -3=0  $ then  $a^3$ is equal to:

(A) $a+1$ (B) $2a+1$ (C) $4a+1$ (D) $4a+3$ (E) $5a+3$

I've tried $a^2 = a + 3$ then multiply by $a$. Doesn't work.

I've tried finding the roots in the standard manners ($x_1 + x_2 = -b/a$ and $x_1x_2 = c/a$ and also the quadratic formula) but of course that doesn't work as they ask it in terms of $a$ and I can't figure it out from the roots directly, so I will be trying your complete algebra approach thanks.

Comment: I've tried $a^2 = a + 3$ then multiply by a. Doesn't work. I've tried finding the roots in the standard manners (x1 + x2 = -b/a and x1*x2 = c/a and also the quadratic formula) but of course that doesn't work as they ask it in terms of a and i can't figure it out from the roots directly, so I will be trying your complete algebra approach thanks.

Comment: No, you don't need the roots.  if you multiply by $a$ you get $a^3=a^2+3a$.  Now, can you rewrite $a^2$?

Comment: Oh, these things always look easy after you see them.  They are often hard to spot though.

Comment: Yeah.. Thanks for pointing it out :)

Comment: I've downvoted and voted to close this question because it looks very much like a homework question and is a [PSQ](http://goo.gl/mLWc8). In the future, please include [more context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960/272831) such as what's holding you back.

Comment: Please follow the guidelines outlined by [How to ask a good question?](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) and [How to ask a homework question?](https://goo.gl/Fyfb22). Low quality questions run the risk of being [closed](https://goo.gl/J58Qwn) and [deleted](https://goo.gl/FmJes1), and repeated closures and deletions may trigger a [question ban](https://goo.gl/7QcTa9). Thank you!

Comment: Your question was put on hold, the message above (and possibly comments) should give an explanation why. (In particular, [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960) might be useful.) You might try to edit your question to address these issues. Note that the next edit puts your post in the review queue, where users can vote whether to reopen it or leave it closed. (Therefore it would be good to avoid minor edits and improve your question as much as possible with the next edit.) Specifically, you could add your attempts mentioned in your comment to the question.

Comment: You have recently added the sentence: "This is a Belgian math olympiad question." Can you provide link to problems from this contest? In particular, is it an ongoing contest?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since the *general* method may not be clear from other answers it may help to describe it explicitly. Given  $\:\!a\:\!$ is a root of a polynomial $\,g(x)\ne 0,\,$ i.e. $\,\color{#c00}{g(a)=0},\,$  suppose we wish to compute $f(a)\,$ for some polynomial $\,f(x).\,$  By the Polynomial Division Algorithm we can divide $\,f(x)\,$ by $\,g(x)$

$$\begin{align} f(x) &=\, r(x)\, +\, q(x)\, g(x),\ \ {\rm with}\ \ \deg r < \deg g\\[.2em]
\smash{\overset{\large x\ =\ a}\Longrightarrow}\ \ f(a) &=\, r(a)\, +\, q(a)\, \color{#c00}{g(a)}\\[.2em]
     &=\, r(a)\ \ \ \ \ {\rm by}\,\ \ \ \ \color{#c00}{g(a) = 0}
\end{align}$$

Since we need only the *remainder* $\,r(a)\,$ it is more efficient to use arithmetic modulo $\,g(x),\,$ vs. the full-blown division algorithm, e.g.  $\,g(x) = x^{\large 2}-x-3\,$ in OP $ $  so

$$\begin{align} \bmod{\,x^{\large 2}\!-\!x\!-\!3}\!:\,\ \color{#c00}{x^{\large 2}}&\equiv \,\color{#0a0}{x\,+\,3}\\[.2em]
\overset{\times\ x}\Longrightarrow\ \ x^{\large 3}&\equiv \color{#c00}{x^{\large 2}}+3x\,\ \ {\rm by}\,\ \ x * {\rm prior}\\[.2em]
  &\equiv  \color{#0a0}{x+3}+3x\\[.2em]
 &\equiv  4x+3\\
\overset{\times\ x}\Longrightarrow\ \ x^{\large 4}&\equiv\ \ldots\ \  \text{as above}\\
\overset{\times\ x}\Longrightarrow\ \ x^{\large 5}&\equiv\ \ldots\ \  \text{as above}
\end{align}\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad$$

Continuing we can rewrite $\,x^{\large 4},x^{\large 5}\ldots$ all as *linear* polynomials in $x$, and use this table to quickly rewrite any polynomial $f(x)$ as a linear polynomial  $\, f\bmod g\,=\, r\,$ in the above notation.

---

**Remark** $ $ In some cases it may be simpler to use Horner nested form, e.g. as [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/32186/242), to reduce $\!\bmod \color{#c00}{x^4}-16$ we rewrite the polynomial in nested form, pulling out factors of $\,\color{#c00}{x^4}\,$ as follows

$$\begin{align}  &\ 3 - 2\ x^3\ \ \ +\ \ \ \,5\ x^5\ \ \ -\ \ \ \ \,11\ x^9 \ \ +\, \ \ 7\ x^{13}\\[.3em]
 =\ &\ 3 - 2\ x^3 + \color{#c00}{x^4}\ (5\ x + \color{#c00}{x^4}\ (-11\ x + \color{#c00}{x^4}\ (7\ x)))\end{align}\qquad\qquad$$

Substituting $\, \color{#c00}{x^4} = 16\ $ above yields the sought remainder of degree $< \color{#c00}4$.

Answer (score 9):

$$\begin{align}0&=a^2-a-3\\a^2&=a+3\qquad\qquad~~~(1)\\a^3&=a^2+3a\\a^3&=(a+3)+3a\qquad\text{by $(1)$}\\a^3&=4a+3\end{align}$$

Answer (score 6):

From the given equation,

$$a^2=a+3.$$

Then multiplying by $a$ and substituting,

$$a^3=a^2+3a=a+3+3a.$$

*Zo simple*.

---

**The "hard" way:**

The roots of the quadratic are $$a=\frac{1\pm\sqrt{13}}2.$$

Then taking the cube (by the binomial theorem),
$$a^3=\frac{1\pm3\sqrt{13}+3\cdot13\pm13\sqrt{13}}8=5\pm2\sqrt{13}.$$

To account for the square root of $13$, you take $4a$, giving $2\pm2\sqrt{13}$ and add $3$ to adjust the integer term.

Answer (score 4):

Another way to approach this is to use $(a^2-a+1)(a+1)=a^3+1$.  Then you can say

$$\begin{align}a^2-a-3&=0\\
a^2-a+1&=4\\
(a^2-a+1)(a+1)&=4(a+1)\\
a^3+1&=4a+4\\
a^3&=4a+3\end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks, I would like to know how you can learn such "tricks". Are the Art of Problem Solving books good for these sort of things?

Comment: @delivosa It's not a "trick". Rather, it is a special case of computing modulo a polynomial - see my answer. This is *algebraically* reified when one studies quotient rings.

Comment: Okay, thank you for that insight. Thought it was some shortcut you just know, still very new to this.